# Composer and IBM Bluemix directory problems

Tags: php, path, composer-php, ibm-cloud

I tried a php app in localhost and it's working, but I dont know how to make it work in Bluemix. It's a php application using Composer. The plugin is installing, but I don't know the directory. In localhost this is working:

`require '/vendor/autoload.php'`;

But in Bluemix I get this error

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: require(/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/prueba.php on line 21
```

In localhost, Composer installs in `/vendor` path...but where can I find it in Bluemix?

Thnaks for the help

Comment: shouldn't that be `./vendor/autoload.php` or just `vendor/autoload.php`?

Comment: Thanks for replying.. the solution if someone have the someone problem

require '/app/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: @lean the path you use is an absolute path (beginning with `/`) I would recommend to use a relative path (not starting with a slash) like @danielgrim mentioned.